# How do we factor out $x^2 - x -2$ in this expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Suppose we're given that

$$x^4 - 2x^3 +x-2$$

How do we factor out $x^2 - x -2$ in this expression?

> $$(x^4 -x^3- 2x^2)-(x^3-x^2-2x)+(x^2-x-2) = x^2(x^2 -x-2)-x(x^2-x-2)+(x^2-x-2) = (x^2-x-2)(x^2-x+1)$$

This satisfies with what we want to get. However, I do not seem to have understood what is done there. Could I get your assistance in order to understand it? Perhaps there's better way of factoring.

Regards

Comment: Miss Wormwood's old-fashioned polynomial division does the job very nicely.  No slick tricks there.

Comment: The source you read splits terms, and adds pairs of cancelling terms, to make the factorisation obvious. When a factor $x^2-x-2$ is known or suspected, polynomial long division is an alternative approach that would work. By the way, we can further factorise viz. $x^2-x-2=(x-2)(x+1)$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Can you explain that way?

Comment: @ncmathsadist To modern students *division* is something a calculator does. And most calculators won't take polynomials as inputs (I know, I know, that's gonna change soon, unless it has already). Don't scare them with outdated procedures where they actually would have to work.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No idea about what you mean by stating that to modern students, division is something a calculator does. I'm trying to understand what my textbook did in order to factor out $x^2 -x-2$.

Comment: @Enzo:  http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/divide_poly/long_division/long_division.html

Comment: @Enzo I think, your way is the best here. I also make it by this way. Practically, it's mach more better.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg But how does that way work?

Comment: @Enzo I posted it. See now.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way is to note that $x^4-2x^3+x-2$ has the simple roots $x=-1$ and $x=2$, which are obvious candidates by the rational root theorem, so your polynomial is divisible by
$$(x+1)(x-2)=x^2-x-2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$x^4-2x^3+x-2 = x^3(x-2)+1(x-2)=(x-2)(x^3+1)=\color{red}{(x-2)(x+1)}(x^2-x+1).$$

---

Regarding the taking a factor out part, we use
$$ab+ac = a(b+c)$$
to factor $a$ out of the terms. In your case, it is $ab+ac+ad = a(b+c+d)$.

Comment: This way will not work for such an example $$x^3 - 2x^2 -3x+6$$ I believe.

Comment: Note that $x^3-2x^2-3x+6 = x^2(x-2)-3(x-2)$.

Comment: How do we get $x^2 -x-2$ from that?

Comment: @enzo you can't, hence $x^2-x-2$ is not a factor of $x^3-2x^2-3x+6$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way: complete the square in  $\rm\color{#c00}{lead\ 2\ terms}$  yielding

$$ \underbrace{\color{#c00}{(x^2\!-\!x)^2} - (\color{#c00}{x^2}\!-\!x)-2}_{\Large \color{#c00}{x^4\ -\ 2x^3}\ +\ x\ -\ 2\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! } = X^2\!-\!X\!-\!2 = (X\!+\!1)(X\!-\!2) = (x^2\!-\!x\!+\!1)\underbrace{(x^2\!-\!x\!-\!2)}_{\Large (x-2)(x+1)}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4-2x^3+x-2=x^4-x^3-2x^2-x^3+x^2+2x+x^2-x-2=$$
$$=x^2(x^2-x-2)-x(x^2-x-2)+(x^2-x-2)=(x^2-x-2)(x^2-x+1).$$

Comment: I did not get how you obtained that.

Comment: @Enzo Is the first step clear?

Comment: Not really, It's a bit unclear. Honestly, splitting terms makes me confused.

Comment: @Enzo See please better: $-2x^3=-x^3-x^3,$ $0=-2x^2+x^2+x^2,$ $x=2x-x$ and $-2=-2.$

Comment: But you could write that $$-2x^3 = -4x^3 + 2x^3$$

Comment: I'm still unable to get the process :(

Comment: @Enzo Because I want to get a factor $x^2-x-2$. I wrote $x^4-x^3-2x^2$ because $x^4-x^3-2x^2=x^2(x^2-x-2)$, which gives us the factor $x^2-x-2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^2 - x -2$ is indeed a factor of $x^4 - 2x^3 + x -2$, that means I can write:

$$ x^4 - 2x^3 + x - 2 = P(x)(x^2 -x - 2)$$

In order to reproduce the $x^4$ term, that means that the leading term of $P(x)$ is $x^2$. Now

$$ x^2(x^2 -x -2) = x^4 -x^3 -2x^2 $$

which is not the same as what we started with. Let's try to salvage the situation by adding/subtracting whatever we need to both sides of this equation in order to make the RHS agree with our original polynomial. We need another $-x^3$, we need to get rid of the $-2x^2$ and we need to add $x-2$:

$$ \begin{align}
x^2(x^2-x-2) -x^3 +2x^2 + x -2 & = x^4 - x^3 -2x^2 - x^3 + 2x^2 + x -2 \\
& = x^4 -2x^3 +x -2
\end{align}$$

We continue the same way, starting with the $-x^3$ term on the LHS. We will try to write $$-x^3 + 2x^2 + x - 2 = Q(x)(x^2 - x -2)$$ We see that the leading term of $Q(x)$ must be $-x$ in order to reproduce the $-x^3$ term.

$$ (-x)(x^2 -x -2) = -x^3 +x^2 + 2x$$

which is not the same as $-x^3 + 2x^2 + x - 2$, so we'll add/subtract whateve we need to both sides: we need an extra $x^2$, we need to take away $x$ and add $-2$:

$$ (-x)(x^2 -x -2) +x^2 - x - 2= -x^3 +x^2 + 2x +x^2 - x - 2 = -x^3 + 2x^2 + x - 2$$

We continue on with what's left in the LHS: we want to write

$$x^2 - x - 2= R(x)(x^2 - x - 2)$$

Obviously R(x) is the constant polynomial $R(x) = 1$. So gathering the pieces together we can say:

$$ \begin{align}
x^4 - 2x^3 + x - 2 &= x^2(x^2-x-2) -x^3 +2x^2 + x -2 \\
&= x^2(x^2-x-2) -x(x^2-x-2) + x^2-x-2 \\
&= x^2(x^2-x-2) -x(x^2-x-2) + 1(x^2-x-2) \\
&= (x^2 - x + 1)(x^2-x-2)
\end{align}$$

Maybe this makes it clearer where the original manipulations came from, but what I did above is pretty much long division (of polynomials) without saying so. In long division, you would arrange as in long division of numbers but instead of calculating successive digits of the (numerical) quotient, you calculate successive *terms* of the (polynomial) quotient. It looks like this:

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
{\color{red}{x^2}} {\color{blue}{-x}} + {\color{green}1} \\
x^2 - x - 2 \enclose{longdiv}{x^4 - 2x^3 + \phantom{2x^2 +} x - 2} \\
     \underline{\color{red}{x^4 - \phantom{2}x^3 - 2x^2}\phantom{+x - 2}} \\
     \phantom{x^4 }\phantom{- 2}-x^3 + 2x^2 + x - 2 \\
     \underline{\color{blue}{-x^3 + x^2 + 2x}\phantom{- 2}} \\
     \phantom{x^4 + -x^3}{x^2 -x -2} \\
     \underline{\color{green}{x^2 -x -2 }}\\
     \underline{0}
\end{array}
$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
x^4-2x^3+x-2&= x^4 + (\color{red}{-2x^3+x-2})\\
&= x^4 + \color{red}{P(x)}\\
&= x^4 + \color{green}{-x^3-2x^2+}(\color{green}{x^3+2x^2}+\color{red}{P(x)})\\
&= \color{blue}{(x^4 + -x^3-2x^2)}+(x^3+2x^2+\color{red}{P(x)})\\
&= (x^2-x-2)(x^2)+(x^3+2x^2+\color{red}{P(x)})\\
&= (x^2-x-2)(x^2)+(x^3+2x^2+\color{red}{-2x^3+x-2})\\
&= (x^2-x-2)(x^2)+(-x^3+2x^2+x-2)\\
&= \dots\\
\end{align}$$

Try comparing the line with blue highlighting with your original problem (e.g. $x^4-x^3-2x^2$). Now, keep going, and try to split up the rest of the polynomial, using the same method.